# dynamically set validation error message in antd form not working with setFields

Tags: reactjs, antd

i am trying to dynamically set error message if email is not ending with dish.com. How i can do that onchange in antd? Below is the code i tried but it is not showing that validation message. Please help.i am using functional component.

```
<Form  ref={formRef}  onFinish={handleFinish} layout="vertical">
    <Form.Item
                      label="Email"
                      name="email"
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          type: "email",
                          // pattern: new RegExp('[a-z0-9]+@dish.com'),
                          message: 'Please provide email',
                        },
                      ]}
                      onChange={(event) => checkEmailExist(event)}
                    >
</Form>


    const checkEmailExist = (event) => {

          if (!event.target.value.includes("@dish.com")) {
             console.log("inside");
     formRef.current.setFields([
              {
                name: 'email',
                errors: ['Please provide with dish.com'],
              },
            ]);
    }}
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit, "It is not working" is too vague.